# Simplifying $\frac{\sin(x)-\csc(x)}{\cos(x)}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification

I'm trying to simplify $\frac{\sin(x)-\csc(x)}{\cos(x)}$, here is what I did:

$\frac{\sin(x)-\csc(x)}{\cos(x)} = \frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}-\frac{\csc(x)}{\cos(x)}=\frac{\sin^2(x)}{\sin(x)\cos(x)}-\frac{1}{\sin(x)\cos(x)}$

Where to get the last equality I multiplied $\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}$ by $\frac{\sin(x)}{\sin(x)}$ and used the identity $\csc(x)=\frac{1}{\sin(x)}$. Now that there is a common denominator, I can continue as so:

$\frac{\sin^2(x)}{\sin(x)\cos(x)}-\frac{1}{\sin(x)\cos(x)}=\frac{\sin^2(x)-1}{\sin(x)\cos(x)}=\frac{-\cos^2(x)}{\sin(x)\cos(x)}=\frac{-\cos(x)}{\sin(x)}=-\cot(x)$

And thus

$\frac{\sin(x)-\csc(x)}{\cos(x)}=-\cot(x)$

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Formatting tip:  To obtain $\sin x$, $\cos x$, $\tan x$, $\csc x$, $\sec x$, $\cot x$, type `$\sin x$`, `$\cos x$`, `$\tan x$`, `$\csc x$`, `$\sec x$`,  `$\cot x$`, respectively.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you are right, more simply

$$\frac{\sin x -\csc x }{\cos x }=\frac{\sin x -\frac1{\sin x }}{\cos x  }=\frac{\sin^2 x -1}{\cos x\sin x  }=-\frac{\cos^2 x}{\cos x\sin x}=-\cot x$$